# The Java library option is missing in Android Studio 4.1 and 4.2.2

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.2

I cannot find Java library when creating a new project with Android Studio 4.2.2.

Screenshot when creating new project:

[image: screenshot when creating new project]

How can I create a Java library with Android Studio 4.2.2?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have tried v4.1 and 4.2 as well and it is missing from those versions?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check the relevant [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/create-java-class):

> 1. Do one of the following:
>
>    - For Windows or Linux, select **File > Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates > Files**.
>    - For macOS, select **Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > File and Code Templates > Files**.
>
> ##### Creating a Java class or type
>
> Android Studio helps you to create new Java classes; enumeration and singleton classes; and interface and
> annotation types based on [file templates](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/create-java-class#templates).
>
> To create a new Java class or type, follow these steps:
>
> 1. In the **Project** window, right-click a Java file or folder, and select **New > Java Class**.
>
>    Alternatively, select a Java file or folder in the **Project**
>    window, or click in a Java file in the Code Editor. Then select **File > New > Java Class**.